# How to display one section only (of a web page)

Tags: html

Good morning everybody.

Maybe this is a simple task, but it's complicated to google, and I can't find a solution.

Let's say I've got an html page like this (let's call this one "main page"):

```
<a name="1">
First content
</a>
<a name="2">
Second content
</a>
<a name="3">
Third content
</a>
etcetera.
```

In another page there are some links, something like this: `<a href="mainpage.html#1">click for first content</a>`, or `<a href="mainpage.html#2">click for second content</a>` and so on.

Of course it works. If, for example, I click the second link, I will see the main page starting from second content.

But that is not what I need. That's because the first content is just above, and it can be seen using the scroll bar, and the third content is just under the second, and it can likely be seen even without scrolling.

What I need is any other content to disappear completely. Just the second content has to be seen (or the first one, or the third: just one each time). I suppose this should be easy, but is there a simple way to do that (anchors or css)?

Thanks

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, if you want to show the three sections as separate pages, have you considered making them into separate files? I mean, that would be the simplest solution, if you always intend to show them separately.

Comment: If you put what content to go to in the query string, like `mainpage.html?content=1` then you can use Javascript to only show that content.

Comment: if you dont want the scrollbar have you tried making it unscrollable?

Comment: you can also hide other content with javascript that reads the hash url fragment

Comment: @Silvio: I thought about it, but the contents are about 300 (books' summaries). As I'm a programmer, not a web designer, I find it easier dealing with one big file rather than 300 small ones. If no other solution will work, I will resign myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need JavaScript to check `location.hash` like so:

```js
window.location.hash="#2";
let a = document.querySelectorAll("a[name]");
a.forEach(function(e) {
  if ("#" + e.getAttribute("name") != location.hash) {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```html
<a name="1">
First content
</a>
<br/>
<a name="2">
Second content
</a>
<br/>
<a name="3">
Third content
</a> etcetera.
```

If you want to see the example in action:

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll("a[name]");
window.onhashchange = () => {
  a.forEach(function(e) {
    if ("#" + e.getAttribute("name") != location.hash) {
      e.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 200%;
}
```

```html
<b>Click the links below to simulate going to this page with a hash</b>
<hr>
<a href="#1">One</a><br/>
<a href="#2">Two</a><br/>
<a href="#3">Three</a><br/>
<hr>
<a name="1">
First content
</a>
<br/>
<a name="2">
Second content
</a>
<br/>
<a name="3">
Third content
</a> etcetera.
```

Comment: your solution looks good, but there are two pages: the one with the links, and the one with the contents. They have to remain distinct.

Comment: @AndreaCarta Then use the first example, but get rid of the `window.location.hash="#2";`. The second example was only for demonstration.

Comment: @AndreaCarta put the code on 'mainpage.html'

Comment: it doesnt' work. This is the "search" page:

<html>
<body>
<a href ="mainpg.html#1">First</a>
<a href ="mainpg.html#2">Second</a>
<a href ="mainpg.html#3">Third</a>
</body>
</html>

This the main page:

<html>
<body>
<script>
let a = document.querySelectorAll("a[name]");
a.forEach(function(e) {
  if ("#" + e.getAttribute("name") != location.hash) {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
})
</script>
<a name="1">1st content</a>
<a name="2">2nd content</a>
<a name="3">3rd content</a>
</body>
</html>

All is shown: only the starting point, as before, is correct.

Comment: at the end your solution worked! it needed an event listener, otherwise it would not have been executed on reloading (hash change did not trigger the reload). Also I added "else {e.style.display = "initial";" otherwise I would not have been able to let other contents resurface on subsequent clicks. I think the solution was very good.

Comment: @AndreaCarta Glad to help :)